# What is the Annotation Shortcut in Xcode11?

Tags: xcode, xcode11

In Xcode 10 it's "⌘ + /", but in Xcode 11 this shortcut key does not work.

Comment: That's the "Comment Selection" shortcut (Xcode -> Editor -> Structure -> Comment Selection).

Comment: It works fine here. Maybe you have some global shortcut that uses the same Shortcut, which causes shortcut conflicts.